# Unable to delete test orders in Opencart 2.0.1.1

Tags: curl, opencart

In my localhost I have no problems when trying to delete my test orders, but after moving to live, I can't delete a single test order that I have done while I was configuring my Opencart (2.0.1.1) web store.

The error message in admin is the following:

> Warning: CURL error Failed to connect to www.turabolt.eu port 80:
>   Connection refused(7)!

I double checked my FTP settings, and it should be correct, since I don't have any problems when uploading product photos for instance.

Do you guys have any idea about this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely due to your server blocking loopback curl request to same domain.  There is a discussion about it and some suggested workarounds on the Opencart forums here:

http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=146714

And another discussion / report of the issue on github here:

https://github.com/opencart/opencart/issues/2567

You should consider contacting your host admin and asking if they can modify the configuration to allow local loopback requests like this.

Comment: Thank you, as per your feedback my hostadmin finally helped me.